# Intellij 13.1.3 on OS X: can't debug Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, debugging, intellij-idea, intellij-13

I write my Ruby code in Intellij and use `Ruby 6.5.2.20140512` plugin for that. But each time I try to debug some Ruby code in my Intellij Idea 13.1.3 I get the next message

> The gem debase required by the debugger is not currently installed.
>   Would you like to install it?

**Problem:** when I choose 'Yes' I get the system crash.

**Question:** is there a way to install that gem debuger manually and tell the Idea a path to it? Or maybe another ways to debug my Ruby code?

Comment: you could always run `gem install debugger` from your terminal

Comment: @MohammadAbuShady already did that. But Indellij doesn't know about that. Intellij still what to install gem debase by itself

Comment: debase is different than debugger, `gem install debase`

Comment: @MohammadAbuShady and how to debug my code with help of debase?

Comment: I'm not sure of intellij with ruby plugin, but in rubymine when you start a debugging session you could add breakpoints and the execution will pause when it passes a breakpoint